# postgres 9.2 counting the number of statuses by ordinal

Tags: sql, postgresql

suppose i have this result set:

```
Location|Company|Account Number|First Check Date|First Status|Second Check Date|Second Status|Third Check Date|Third Status|Fourth Check Date|Fourth Status|Fifth Check Date|Fifth Status
Westeros|Acme Corp.|1014541|8/23/2018|Denied||||||||
Westeros|Acme Corp.|1014544|8/23/2018|Pending||||||||
Westeros|Acme Corp.|1014561|8/23/2018|Pending||||||||
Westeros|Sirius Cybernetics Corp|1014562|8/22/2018|Finalized||||||||
Westeros|Sirius Cybernetics Corp|1014573|8/23/2018|Pending||||||||
Westeros|MomCorp|1014579|8/22/2018|Denied||||||||
Dorne|MomCorp|1018984|8/20/2018|Pending||||||||
Dorne|Sirius Cybernetics Corp|1019017|8/22/2018|Pending||||||||
The North|MomCorp|1033591|8/16/2018|Pending||||||||
The North|MomCorp|1033910|8/16/2018|Not Found||||||||
The North|Amerigroup|1033964|8/16/2018|Partial Payment||||||||
The North|MomCorp|1034036|8/22/2018|Paid||||||||
The North|MomCorp|1034041|8/23/2018|Partial Payment||||||||
Iron Islands|AG White|1175033|8/22/2018|Pending||||||||
Stormlands|foobar|1220179|8/14/2018|Not Found|8/21/2018|Not Found||||||
```

which is returnd from a query that can be boiled down to

```
select Location,Company,Account Number,First Check Date,First Status,Second Check Date,Second Status,Third Check Date,Third Status,Fourth Check Date,Fourth Status,Fifth Check Date,Fifth Status
from subselect as results
```

what i an trying to do is generate a count of elements in each status column. 
for example the first status count would be 15, the second would be 1 and the rest are 0.

I have tried doing this with `over()` and using a `sum(case when 'first_status' then1 else 0 end)` but nothing seems to give correct results.

any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: It would help more, if posted the table's structure as `CREATE TABLE` statement, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the expected result with that sample data, than a (badly formatted) result along with an obviously invalid query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the missing values are `NULL`, you can do:

```
select r.*,
       count(status1) over () as status1_cnt,
       count(status2) over () as status2_cnt,
       . . .
from subselect as results
```

However, the empty statuses might be something else, such as `''`.  If so, a simple approach is:

```
select r.*,
       count(nullif(status1, '')) over () as status1_cnt,
       count(nullif(status2, '')) over () as status2_cnt,
       . . .
from subselect as results
```